# Persistent screen session inside Docker container

Tags: docker, gnu-screen

I am trying to create a Docker container with screen session running some script.
Dockerfile contains

```
CMD screen -S session1 ./testLinux
```

When I run it in detached mode it closes immediately, saying

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

How do I run persistent screen session inside detached docker container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum -y install screen && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
CMD screen -S session1 sleep 99999
```

when I run it with `docker run <imageID>` I get `Must be connected to a terminal.`

Screen needs a terminal (tty) to function. The solution is to add `-tid` to the run flags, from the help:

```
 -d, --detach                         Run container in background and print container ID
 -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
 -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ for reference.

Comment: This is not a solution, I am trying to run it in detached session.

Comment: Then use `-d`, added in answer.